# MVC + jQuery - Load a Table with large number of rows without blocking the Browser UI

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, asynchronous

I have a MVC view with a table that returns hundreds of rows. It's taking to long to the browser to present it.

I'd like to use jQuery to make async calls to the server to get chunks of rows (10 each tiem for instance) and draw it one chunk at time to give the user the sense that something is being done.

How can I do it? Taking in consideration that I don't know the total number of rows. I need to load them until the server signals that it has finished (or timed out).

Please, if possible, I'd like to have a step by step solution.

Thanks...

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: I don't see how. I'm not looking for opinion I need the jQuery code solution to make the async calls and get the table filled. I couldn't find any solution in the web that didn't involve some kind of interaction (like scrolling) or knowing previously the number of rows that will be returned...

Comment: *"Please, if possible, I'd like to have a step by step solution."* ... Unfortunately, Stack Overflow isn't a "step by step solution" site. If you don't know where to start, Google is your answer. If you've already started and have some code that doesn't work as you expect, come to SO and post it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need [infinite scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/).

**EDIT:**

You can set `bufferPx` option to some very high value to make it feel like the load is not happening on scrolling, e.g.

```
bufferPx: 2000 // load at least 2000 pixels worth of data
```

Comment: I thought about it but I don't want the table to be filled when scrolled. It has to be filled independently of the user interaction. Just enable the records to appear as they are loaded one chunk at a time.

Comment: @SirGallahad there's no need to load ALL of the rows anyway. See edited answer for a way to make the user feel like there is no loading happening when scrolling.

Comment: I've download and make the demo work... It's nice but It is not good for me 'cause It requires a navigator and you need to scroll first to allow it to trigger. The prefetch does not work as I need.